# Convert Int to Collection.IndexDistance

Tags: swift, generics, collections

I have a struct that incrementally processes `Collection`s.

```
struct Foo<T: BidirectionalCollection>
    where T.Iterator.Element == UInt8,
          T.SubSequence: BidirectionalCollection,
          T.SubSequence.Iterator.Element == T.Iterator.Element,
          T.SubSequence.Index == T.Index,
          T.SubSequence.IndexDistance == T.IndexDistance,
          T.SubSequence.SubSequence == T.SubSequence
{
    private var state: T.IndexDistance = 0

    mutating func process(_ foo: T) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I'd like to keep track on a `T.IndexDistance` internally (e.g. count the total number of `T.IndexDistance`s processed).

However, I'd also like to compare this distance with normal `UInt`s, and also set it from normal `UInt`s.

Problem is, I don't seem to find a way to convert the `UInt` to a `T.IndexDistance`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let someUInt: UInt = 42
let indexDistance = T.IndexDistance(IntMax(someUInt))
```